# Is it possible to finish Diablo III on Inferno difficulty without using the Auction Houses?

Tags: diablo-iii

It is what it is.

I'm currently in Act I in Hell difficulty, and even by this point I've noticed that a lot of the gear I've gotten isn't *always* level appropriate.

With all the seething rage in the forums, I just want to make sure that it's **realistic to expect to be able to complete the game without resorting to either one of the two AHs**.

Comment: flagged as not constructive. All items on AH were found somewhere, so you can get the better items while farming

Comment: @Novarg: I don't believe this question fits the "Not Constructive" close reason, which is aimed at questions which will elicit discussions, opinions, and polling. This question has a concrete answer, that it *is* possible, as both you and Blem have stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to finish the game on Inferno without using the Auction Houses, but it will take a lot of farming to get it done.

In Inferno only 41.3%-65.1%(depending on act you are in) of the gear that drops will be iLvl 61-63 and even less of that gear will actually be useful. So the time it will take to gather the gear needed to progress through Inferno without using the Auction House would be rather large and I would definitely recommend at least using the gold auction house, unless you got an excessive amount of free time for farming gear.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now know what's on my agenda for tomorrow!